# Bootstrap Material Design cdn

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, bootstrap-material-design

I'd like to use Bootstrap Material design, and the github page says that I can get it from [jsdelivr.com](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!bootstrap.material-design). But then the [Getting Started](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#getting-started) page says:

> Once copied you need to initialize the material javascript by adding
>   the following javascript to your site,
>
> ```
> $.material.init()
> ```

The integration page at jsdelivr says to use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.material-design/0.3.0/css/material-wfont.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.material-design/0.3.0/css/material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
```

But it looks like material-wfont.min.css is returning 404. It's hard to verify if everything is working right or not because I don't know what to expect the new look and feel to be.

If I use the cdn links, so I need to use `$.material.init()`?

Comment: http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!bootstrap.material-design check what you need from there. Only fonts in there is the roboto font and icons. so i would include those 2 instead of wfont, since i dont know either what wfont should be like. surely because there is not css file indicated as such.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the tags to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/roboto.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Download it

It is easier if you download the files from the [Github Page](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design).
You can have more information in http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/.

### Use bower

```
bower install bootstrap-material-design
```

You'll also need jQuery (jquery.com) and the original Bootstrap from getbootstrap.com before adding the Material Design JavaScript files

Comment: This question is about [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).